# Proof $\frac1nS_n\stackrel{\mathbb P}{\rightarrow}\mu$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> If $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are $\text{i.i.d.}$ with $\mathbb E\:|X_1|<\infty$ and $\mathbb E\:X_1=\mu<\infty$ then $$\frac1nS_n\stackrel{\mathbb P}{\rightarrow}\mu$$

I got the proof:

Let $\color{red}{Y_n=|X_1|\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}}$. For each $\omega\in \Omega$, $\color{red}{|X_1(\omega)|<\infty}$, so $Y_n\stackrel{\color{red}{\textrm{why?}}}{\rightarrow}0\textrm{ a.s.}$ Since $|Y_n|\leq|X_1|$ which is integrable, by the **DCT** we have $\mathbb E\:Y_n\rightarrow0$. Further, observe that $\color{red}{Y_n\geq n\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}}$, so $\mathbb E\:Y_n\geq n\mathbb P(|X_1|>n)$. Thus, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\mathbb P(|X_1|>x)=0$.

Next, consider $Z_n=X_1\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|x_1|\leq n\}}$. Again, since $|X_1(\omega)|<\infty$, $Z_n\stackrel{\color{red}{\textrm{why?}}}{\rightarrow} X_1\textrm{ a.s.}$ Thus, we can apply **DCT** to obtain $\mu_n=\mathbb E\:Z_n\rightarrow\mathbb E\:X_1=\mu$. The result then follows by the weak LLN.

---

But I didn't manage to understand the red marked line. Like:

- How they came with idea for such $Y_n$ r.v.?
- How $|X_1|<\infty$ implies $Y_n\rightarrow0?$
- Why $Y_n\geq n\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}?$

Maybe all of my question require another reference theorem but I really want to know all of those Why.

Thanks for your time and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly the famous Weak Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: Regarding your questions: Assume, there is $A\subset \Omega$ with $P(A)>0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}Y_n(\omega)\neq 0$ for $\omega \in A$. This would mean that the indicator is always $1$ for those $\omega$, hence $|X_1(\omega)|=\infty$. This would contradict $E[|X_1|]<\infty$. 

For your last question: If $\omega\in \Omega$ is such that the indicator is $0$, the left and the right hand side are both $0$, so assume, that the indicator is $1$. Then $Y_n(\omega)=|X_n(\omega)|\geq n$ by the indicator function.

Comment: **This would mean that the indicator is always $1$ for those $\omega$, hence $|X_1(\omega)|=\infty$** Could you explain me why $|X_1(\omega)|=\infty?$ @GrafZahl

Comment: Fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and assume $|X_1(\omega)|<\infty$. Then there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|X_1(\omega)|<N$. Hence for all $n\geq N$ we have $1(|X_1(\omega)|>n)=0$, so $|Y_n(\omega)|=0$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: One last question, Why define $Y_n=|X_1|\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}$ with $|X_1|$ but $Z_n=X_1\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{|x_1|\leq n\}}$ with only $X_1?$ You can turn all your comments to an answer. I will accept it as an answer, @GrafZahl

Answer (score 1):

Proving $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]<\infty \Rightarrow Y_1\to 0$ a.s.:

For almost every $\omega\in \Omega$ it must be $|X_1(\omega)|<\infty$, because the expected value is finite. For those $\omega$ there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $|X_1(\omega)|<N$. This means $\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1(\omega)|>n\}}=0$ and thus $Y_n(\omega)=0$ for $n\geq N$. This yields $Y_n(\omega)\to 0$ for almost every $\omega$.

Why do we define $Y_n=\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}|X_1|$ but $Z_n=\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|\leq n\}}X_1$? And why is $Z_n\to X_1$ a.s.?

The whole point is that $Z_n\to X_1$ a.s. is equivalent to $|Z_n-X_1|\to 0$ a.s..
But $$|Z_n-X_1|=|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|\leq n\}}X_1-X_1|=|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}X_1|=\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|>n\}}|X_1|=Y_n$$
for which we have seen that it goes to zero a.s.